# NSManagedObject changedValues ignoring string value

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a subclass of NSManagedObject on which there's a "currency" attribute. This attribute is a 3 letters string. When I change it from "USD" to "CAD", and then call `changedValues` on the object, changedValues returns an empty dictionary. Is that the normal behaviour?

I save the managedObjectContext first, then change the attribute, then call changedValues.

This attribute is: not transient, optional, not indexed, no default value.

EDIT: Thx for the help guys I found a bug in my code. Now it works just fine.

Comment: can you show some code regarding the value changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a bug in my code. Now it works just fine. ;)

I was using a delegate method to update the object from another viewController. When coming back from that viewController I saved the managedObjectContext in `viewWillAppear` which basically erased the changedValues.

Comment: The answer as is in not useful. Please share some context.

Comment: Do no forget to mark it as resolved whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do it before you save the context.

[NSManagedObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/changedValues)

> changedValues
>
> Returns a dictionary containing the keys and (new) values of
>   persistent properties that have been changed since last fetching or
>   ***saving*** the receiver.

Comment: OP **is** doing it before saving the context

Comment: Yep just noticed that. Disregard this answer.